# Simple ajax clock works in everything except for IE for some reason

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Here is my simple ajax function:

```
var callback = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Timer",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response); // Fails, but only in IE10
            $("#target").html(response);
        }
    });
}

setInterval(callback, 1000);
```

and the Controller/Action:

```
public String Timer()
{
    Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString()); // Shows correctly in all browsers
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

which works fine in Opera, Chrome, Firefox, but not IE10 for the weirdest reason. In every other browser, the `console` logs the current time but in IE10, it keeps logging the same time over and over again. I put a breakpoint on my `Timer` method, and it hits the method correctly, but somehow when it gets back to the `success` callback it reports the wrong time. Why would that happen?

Comment: Caching most likely. also, ajax inside setInterval is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Oh, why would an ajax request be cached? That seems almost counter-productive.

Comment: Please use a promise object here and check when $.when so you don't hang my browser.

Comment: Oh this isn't production by any stretch of the imagination. I'm just getting started with ajax, and wanted to write a simple test. But yeah, can you point me in the direction of how to do 'promise objects'?

Comment: he's referreing to [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/). basically have the ability to execute a callback when your ajax finishes

Comment: you don't need $.when unless there's more than one promise object that you are tracking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cache maybe?
try setting `cache:false` in the ajax options

Comment: That worked. Why would an ajax request be cached? That seems really dumb.

Comment: It does seem counter-intuitive, and it burned me recently. As far as I could find, it's only GET requests that get cached.

Comment: It's an optimal solution when requesting the same data repeatedly over the wire. Some application delayed their common data loading to have better page loading time. Having those common/static data in cache actually helped with that.

Comment: IE is notorious for caching GET requests.  Make sure that you're happy to allow your GET requests to be cached by IE or explicitly force it to never cache those particular requests.  I've run into this several times myself.

Answer (score 1):

In safari and some older browsers, (from what I've experienced till now, `cache:false` doesnt seem to work sometimes). for a more cross browser compatible solution, you could add a `data` option to the `ajax()` call and add a random number generator as a parameter. It would be something like this.

```
var callback = function () {
 $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/Timer",

    //start random number generator
    data : { r: Math.random() }
    //end random number generator

    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response); // Fails, but only in IE10
        $("#target").html(response);
    }
 });
}
```

This way, everytime a server call happens, a new random number will be generated, and since the data is different from the previous requests, `ajax` requests wont be cached and will ensure a fresh server call every single time.

Answer (score 0):

edit under package and set cache:false in your CSS and call each intermediate function under main class